# Notepad++ change text color?

Tags: interface, notepad++, mockups

I'm using Notepad++ to mock up ISPF screens. I've used StyleConfigurator to select an appropriate font, colored it green, and set a black background.

How do I permanently change the color of selected text?

E.g., if I have CUSTOMER NAME: THALECRESS, how do I make CUSTOMER NAME: blue while leaving THALECRESS green?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can Change it from:

Menu Settings -> Style Configurator

See on screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your screenshot isn't displaying. Can you describe what I change in Style Configurator?

Comment: OK,
Go in Menu Settings->Style Configurator-> 
than in  "Langugage" List select Global Styles. After in Style list select "Selected text colour" and after you will get screen as shown on screenshot. On right side of window you will be able tyo change colour of selected text.

Comment: Take note that you can't permanently save the colour of the selected text. I wanted that feature, but unfortunately Notepad++ is only a text editor, not a word processor. Sigh.

Answer (score 19):

A little late reply, but what I found in Notepad++ v7.8.6 is, on RMB (Right Mouse Button), on selection text, it gives an option called "Style token" where it shows "Using 1st/2nd/3rd/4th/5th style" to highlight the selected text in different pre-defined colors

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "User-Defined Language" option available at the notepad++.
You do not need to do the xml-based hacks, where the formatting would be available only in the searched window, with the formatting rules.

Sample for your reference [here](https://darekkay.com/2014/09/10/turn-notepad-into-a-log-file-analyzer/).