# Notepad++ How to change colour/color of a piece of text within other text

Tags: notepad++

In Notepadd++ I am using a custom made language to view easily CNC G/M Code that is shown in continuous lines. Here is a small extract of the code

`M436(AGB CLOSE)
G4U0.2
M6
G4U0.2
G13.1G18G97G99G113
M89M94M96M124
G0X#814+1.0Z-1.0`

I would like to highlight pieces such as G13.1 or G0 or M89 or G99 etc. individually with different colours.
How should I add these in the styler boxes?

Kind regards

George

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874260/notepad-change-text-color

Comment: His answer will work on single words. Unfortunately I don't have words that are separated by spaces. All my text is one complete line without any spaces in it.

Comment: Actually there are several lines but all of them don't have spaces in them.